# How to Best Store Historical Shopping Cart Data

Tags: mysql, json

I am having a issue with a MySQL table design. Originally, this data comes from a JSON dataset that records all items that a customer as added into their cart along with other information. My problem is figuring out how I should store this data. The goal is to be able to query all parts that a user has added and compare it to the final cart contents to see what items have been added and removed. This may also be a query solvable problem but I am fairly new to MySQL.

Also, this data needs to be in MySQL.

Thanks for any help!

Here is a small example of my parts table:

[image: Here is a small example of my parts table.]

Here is an example of the JSON, The file is arounf 1 gb so it is a bit hard to find a good example that I can fit in the question.

```
{
    "account_num": "TEMPZVNVB",
    "loginid": 70196,
    "itemavail": {
      "3": "In Stock",
      "2": "In Stock",
      "1": "In Stock"
    },
    "ads_country": "US",
    "englishsessionredirected": false,
    "isloginok": true,
    "returnpage": "/newweb/gauges/convection_kjlc_2.cfm",
    "accounts": "CreditCard",
    "shoppingcart": [
      {
        "ReturnPage": "/newweb/",
        "Availability": "In Stock",
        "subtotal": 78.4,
        "description": "GASKET, COPPER",
        "PartNo": "0800",
        "Custom": false,
        "unitprice": 78.400,
        "ArrayName": "Session.CartItems1",
        "extprice": 78.400,
        "Checked": false,
        "EmailNeeded": false,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "FromSaved": false
      },
      {
        "ReturnPage": "/newweb",
        "Availability": "In Stock",
        "subtotal": 27.35,
        "description": "10/PKG",
        "PartNo": "0275",
        "Custom": false,
        "unitprice": 27.350,
        "ArrayName": "Session.CartItems2",
        "extprice": 27.350,
        "Checked": false,
        "EmailNeeded": false,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "FromSaved": false
      },
      {
        "ReturnPage": "/newweb",
        "Availability": "In Stock",
        "subtotal": 385.0,
        "description": "CONVECTION ",
        "PartNo": "03LL",
        "Custom": false,
        "unitprice": 385.000,
        "ArrayName": "Session.CartItems3",
        "extprice": 385.000,
        "Checked": false,
        "EmailNeeded": false,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "FromSaved": false
      }
```

Comment: Offtopic: *"MySQL not Mongo which I am sure would be more effective. "*  Thats like comparing apples with pears as both databases are solving different problems.. Ontopic: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) no images please...

Comment: Also a sample part of the JSON file also might be handly, so we know whats in there and get a better feeling for the data..

Comment: I added in a sample of the JSON file. It is a part of the file so it is not valid.